# Alternative to static arraylist, for storing data and to be accessed in other package

Tags: java, static, package, static-members

I am working on a project, in which i have a list that is populated whenever service is being called. This list is in the Service Adapter class, which is being called whenever a service is being called. So now I have to access this list in another package, without making it static. I am requesting a server for the data through the service calls

Rightnow I have made this list static, and have a public class in the same package, with static getter and setter methods for it. So I can access this this from another package through this class.

But the problem is I dont want to have a static list, since static variables live in the memory as long as the program executes, and this causing many performance issues. And if there are multiple requests, then this list is with all the request, I want it with specific request only.

Can anyone suggest an alternative of static variable??

Skeleton:

```
package pa;

class ServAdp { //called multiple times, whenever service is called
    static arraylist; 
    XYZ.set(arraylist);
}
  class XYZ{
       get(arr);
       set(arr);
}
```

---

```
package pp;

 class WantTheArraylistHere{
     XYZ.get(arraylist);
 }
```

Don't want to make the list static! Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this class **singleton**. Then there will be only one instance and you do not need to make this as static as well.

Comment: which class? ServiceAdapter? and what exctly is singleton?

Comment: Yes make the ServiceAdapter a Singleton class and populate the list in constructor and then you can get then list something like serviceAdapterObj.getList()

Comment: thanku, but ServiceAdp class is an abstract class, so i think i cant do that. making XYZ class as singleton would help and getting the obj of this singleton class to populate the list? And making a class singleton just means making the constructor private right?

Comment: hey using singleton also, ill be creating a static object, so statics are still there. Is this object get destroyed when the thread executing it dies? otherwise it defeats my purpose of removing static please answer?

Comment: You can make the Service Adapter class **public** and list as private , and you can access list by setter/getters